# Build jquery url in $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a $.ajax call and send some data to a php file, my php file is located in a

component's folder and my js file in the webroot folder, how can I make the url portion of the $.ajax point to the right php file, to get to the php file from the JS file I need to do the following

> ../../../src/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php

but when I do the same in the $.ajax call like

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../../../src/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php' ,
            data: "accessToken" + access_token, 
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function (response) {
                console.log("data coming back from Auth.php" +response);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }  
   });
```

I only get

> http://localhost:8765/src/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php- 404 not found

How can I build the url?

Comment: It says http://localhost:8765/src/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php not found, let me ask you, the name of the project is SRC? If not probably you'll need another ../ or use the entire path (http://localhost:8765/nameoftheproject/src/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php-

Comment: _“to get to the php file from the JS file”_ - that’s not what you need anyway, where your “JS file” is located is irrelevant - relative URLs are resolved based on the URL of the _document_ your JS code is currently running in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a framework or if you have build routing yourself, for all other pages of the website. Then similar to those, you will have to create (assign) a new route to the method() added in your AuthComponent.php for example:

```
Route: http://localhost:8765/authcomponent/method_name
Pointing to: /src/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php::methodName()
```

Then, your final JavaScript code will look like:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8765/authcomponent/method_name' ,
        data: "accessToken" + access_token, 
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function (response) {
            console.log("data coming back from methodName() of AuthComponent.php file" +response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I would rather pass in the complete URL (if there's any chance you can pass on your domain to the JS code).
Sometimes, if you are compiling your code, the actual relative path might not be the same as your directory's ordering when running the code (e.g. the JS might be being compiled to run from a single location in a different folder within your site's dir).

Answer (score 0):

you can't use absolute path as url ,if for example your document root  is something called 'public_html' directory ,i mean your site name pointing to this folder and inside that your file AuthComponent.php is placed that your url is  sitename/AuthComponent.php will make call to your file.